# Rxjs observable with Inner subscription taking long time and outer observable executed firstly in subsequent requests

Tags: rxjs, nested, observable, subscription

I have a button that starts a Observable, then I subscribe to the result and nested I have a subscription that depends on the previous Observable result.

```
this.getData(params).subscribe(result => {
    // Make some first level process
    console.log('[Outter Execution]: ',result);

    this.getInnerData(result).subscribe(res => {
        // Make some inner level process
        console.log('[Inner Execution]: ',res);
    });
});
```

Depends on the click speed of the user, the sequence is not the same:

```
//User click slowly

[Outer Execution]
[Inner Execution]

[Outer Execution]
[Inner Execution]

//User start clicking quickly

[Outer Execution]
[Inner Execution]

[Outer Execution]
[Inner Execution]

[Outer Execution]
[Outer Execution]
[Outer Execution]

[Inner Execution]
[Inner Execution]
[Inner Execution]

[Outer Execution]
[Inner Execution]
[Outer Execution]
[Inner Execution]
```

As you can see, if the nested subscription take long time and the user click again before the inner subscription is resolved, the first [Outer Execution] message is logged out before the inner execution was solved. Some time later, the previous long time inner subscriptions are solved and the logged messages are returned.

I tried to use **switchMap** and **mergeMap** operators without success.

[Edited]: The functionality that I need, is the execution as a block, and the next outer execution needs to be executed after the first execution complete (outer and inner subscription).

Comment: what is the issue and expected behavior?

Comment: I need to execute at same time (outer and inner), and the next outer execution needs to be executed after the first complete execution (outer and inner subscription)

Comment: You were on the right track with using switchMap. It is not normally a good idea to have a subscription within a subscription as it is difficult to manage the subscriptions and ensure they are properly unsubscribed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that the processing *waits*, you need to use `concatMap` on the main Observable, not on the dependent Observable. Otherwise it is not waiting for the set.

I forked before your latest changes, but this is what I came up with that seems to work:

```
  private clickSubject = new Subject<number>();
  clickAction$ = this.clickSubject.asObservable();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clickAction$
      .pipe(
        concatMap(value => this.mainProcess(value)
          .pipe(
            mergeMap(x => this.dependantProcess(x))
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe();
  }

  onClick(value) {
    // Emits a value into the action stream
    this.clickSubject.next(value);
  }

  mainProcess(value) {
    console.log("[Emitted] Main", value);
    return of(value).pipe(delay(10));
  }

  dependantProcess(value) {
    console.log("[Emitted] Dependent", value);
    return of(value).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
```

Notice that the `concatMap` is used to wait for the mainProcess.

- This code reacts to user clicks by defining an action stream using an RxJS `Subject`.
- Each time the user clicks the button, the action stream emits.
- The action stream pipeline uses `concatMap` to cache the request and wait to process it until the prior request is processed.
- When the main process emits, the dependent process executes.
- When the pipeline is complete (main and its dependent process), then the next cached request is processed by the `concatMap`.

Make sense?

You can find the updated code here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dependent-order-deborahk

Comment: it works like a charm. I will review your process and course in order to get a better knowledge for some complex use cases.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to work with RxJS and without a specific example here it is difficult to provide you with a specific answer. Best I can do is provide you an example from my code and hope it is close to what you are trying to accomplish.

I have products with their suppliers. When I get a product, it has an array of supplier Ids. So I need to get the product, then get the suppliers within that operation. (Sound similar to your scenario?)

Here is my code:

```
  selectedProductSuppliers$ = this.selectedProduct$
    .pipe(
      filter(selectedProduct => Boolean(selectedProduct)),
      switchMap(selectedProduct =>
        forkJoin(selectedProduct.supplierIds.map(supplierId => this.http.get<Supplier>(`${this.suppliersUrl}/${supplierId}`)))
      ),
      tap(suppliers => console.log('product suppliers', JSON.stringify(suppliers)))
    );
```

This code uses a `switchMap` to ensure that if the user clicks multiple times it will switch to the latest selection.

It then uses a `forkJoin` to process each of the supplier Ids, issuing an http get request to retrieve each suppliers data and join them in one emitted array.

The return value is an `Observable<Supplier[]>`

You can find a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS

UPDATE:

If you change the above code to use `concatMap` instead of `switchMap` it will process each request, waiting for one to finish before executing the next one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I just applied this process, but I need to finish all the previous block (main and dependant observable, in your example main is selectedProduct$ and the dependant is the HTTP get for each supplierIds). The order should be, wait to the first sequence (main and dependant) to be completed before continue with the second clic process (I cannot cancel previous one or delay the dependant process). But when the user clic quickly, main observable is executed and later, when the dependant is finished, it shows the dependant result.

Comment: So if they click quickly, you want to still process *each* click, not just the last (most recent) one? If so, then you can try `concatMap` instead of `switchMap`.

Comment: I just created a sample of the needed usage with some data to ilustrate this process  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b6hia7 (the app.component.ts) If you clic one and wait, the process is correct, but If you clic one several times quickly the process is not sequential although I used mergeMap or concatMap (as you updated it).

Comment: Is your dependent process only emitting one item? If so, you don't need the `forkJoin`. In my example above, each product selection was issuing *multiple* http requests to get the list of suppliers for the product. Also, will your processes be synchronous or async? The `of` emits synchronously.

Comment: The dependant process emit one item or array in async way. I updated the stackblitz in order to avoid the use of the `of` . Main and dependant are async but the complete process needs to be as a block.

Comment: The question is, how can delay or stop a new starting observable process (a new clic) until the previous one is completed (main and descendant)?

Comment: Another option is to disable the button. :-) But I think the answer you may be looking for is my *other* answer here.